# Get Term ID from URL

Tags: views, taxonomy-terms

Possible to get the current URL then grab the term id from it.

com/fishing-report/lakename

lakename being the term. Can i get the Term ID?

Comment: from code you could see $_SERVER['request_uri'] that holds the uri

Comment: Do you need it for views?

Comment: No not in a view. Doing this inside a custom module. Thinking i need to get the current path then grab the term id from it. If that makes any sense.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Basically you would have to do:

```
$path = current_path();
$path_array = explode('/', $path); // Doing this you would get the array of all the elements that there in the url.
```

Once you have the array of items in the array, you would have to do

```
$term_name = $path_array[1];
```

So in **$term_name you would have lakename**, which is your **term name**.

Once you have the name, simply do

```
$term_object = taxonomy_get_term_by_name($term_name);
```

**$term_object would have the object of the term.**

For more detail: https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules!taxonomy!taxonomy.module/function/taxonomy_get_term_by_name

Answer (score 0):

Use [`taxonomy_get_term_by_name()`](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules%21taxonomy%21taxonomy.module/function/taxonomy_get_term_by_name/7) & [`arg()`](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/includes%21bootstrap.inc/function/arg/7) functions to get a taxonomy id from a URL term name. For example, from the URL above...

```
  $term = arg(1);
  $terms = taxonomy_get_term_by_name($term);
  $tid = (count($terms) > 0) ? array_pop(array_keys($terms)) : null;
```

Note: `taxonomy_get_term_by_name()` will return zero or multiple terms (it outputs an array of found taxonomy object with the tid being the keys) so you might need to check to see any term objects are returned.

Comment: It should be arg(2) instead of arg(1).

Comment: Based on the URL I presumed "com" was the end of the ".com" (i.e. the domain), hence `arg(1)`. But yeah, if it's part of the path it would be `arg(2)`.

Comment: I too am updating my answer.. Based on the assumption of yours..:)